# How to avoid wrapping response with "content" when returning ViewModel in controller action?

Tags: php, json, viewmodel, zend-framework2

Using Zend Framework 2 and an AbstractRestfulController where the getList action is implemented like this:

```
public function getList() {
    return new ViewModel(array(
        'entities' = array(1 => array(/*..*/), 2 => array(/*..*/))
    ));
}
```

I've added the JsonStrategy to the view manager so when my UA sends `Accept: text/html` ZF2 uses the correct view to format the data. When my UA sends `Accept: application/json` ZF2 (correctly) responds with `application/json` and JSON encodes the data.

But now the all the entities are wrapped inside a 'content' node (the `ViewModel::$captureTo` property).

If the action controller returns a JsonModel I can avoid this. But then the JsonStrategy always responds with application/json, without checking Accept.

Is there any way to avoid it while still using the ViewModel, and not the JsonModel?

Answer (score 1):

For get a solution i do something like this:

1 - Create a new MasterControllerClass, my new controllers "extends MasterControllerClass"

```
abstract class MasterControllerClass extends AbstractActionController 
private $_jsonFlag = false;

public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $this->preDispatch($e);
    $action = parent::onDispatch($this->getEvent());
    $this->postDispatch($e);
    return $action;
}

public function postDispatch(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $this->_jsonFlag ?: $this->viewConfig($e);
}

public function json($value, $sucess = true)
{
    $this->_jsonFlag = true;
    return new \Zend\View\Model\JsonModel(array(
        'data' => $value,
        'success' => $sucess,
    ));
}
```

2 - In my controller i will call the $this->json('values to pass to javascript', true or false, true == success, false == fail)

It's solve my problem, now i can pass json to my javascripts.

Comment: I want my controllers to be completely oblivious about how the response is sent, it's up the view layer to decide if it should be JSON or HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been addressed in [Zend Framework 2.0.4](http://framework.zend.com/blog/zend-framework-2-0-4-released.html), but not in a perfect way. They have added a new controller plugin called `acceptableViewModelSelector` which one can use like this:

```
class SomeController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $acceptCriteria = array(
        'Zend\View\Model\JsonModel' => array(
            'application/json',
        ),
        'Zend\View\Model\FeedModel' => array(
            'application/rss+xml',
        ),
    );

    public function apiAction()
    {
        $viewModel = $this->acceptableViewModelSelector($this->acceptCriteria);

        // Potentially vary execution based on model returned
        if ($viewModel instanceof JsonModel) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

When it chooses to create an JsonModel, the response will be correctly rendered without the "content" wrapper. Hoped for an more elegant solution so one could avoid view logic in the controllers, but the fix was not created to addressed issue directly.